# Why am I getting this Authentication required error even though I am using my client id and client secret for the Foursquare API?

Tags: python-2.7, api, foursquare

I getting back into Python and wanted to use the pyfoursquare package to access the Foursquare API. I'm trying to get information about venues using the venues method in the API class. I'm primarily trying to find out whether a venue page is verified with Foursquare or not. When I provide my client id, client secret, and venue id I keep getting back an error that states "Authentication required", which doesn't makes sense because I'm providing that information. Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
import pyfoursquare as foursquare
client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
callback = ""
auth = foursquare.OAuthHandler(client_id, client_secret, callback)
api = foursquare.API(auth)
result = api.venues("4e011a3e62843b639cfa9449")
print result[0].name
```

Let me know if you would like to see the error message. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are skipping the step of grabbing your OAuth2 access token, so you're not technically authenticated.

Have a look at the following instructions, under "How to Use It":

https://github.com/marcelcaraciolo/foursquare

The lines that might be useful to you are:

```
#First Redirect the user who wish to authenticate to.
#It will be create the authorization url for your app
auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
print 'Please authorize: ' + auth_url

#If the user accepts, it will be redirected back
#to your registered REDIRECT_URI.
#It will give you a code as
#https://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/?code=CODE
code = raw_input('The code: ').strip()

#Now your server will make a request for
#the access token. You can save this
#for future access for your app for this user
access_token = auth.get_access_token(code)
print 'Your access token is ' + access_token
```